# Apache Configuration - Domain with Hyphen

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

Having a strange issue configuring apache.

I've got 4 domains

- www.mydomain.tld
- www.my-domain.tld
- www.anotherdomain.tld
- www.another-domain.tld

I've configured named virtualhost for each of the domains.

mydomain.tld, my-domain.tld and anotherdomain.tld works correctly but another-domain.tld isn't working correctly.

Apache seems to be picking up the virtualhost for anotherdomain.tld and serving it rather than the another-domain.tld

both have the server name set correctly

- ServerName anotherdomain.tld

and

- ServerName another-domain.tld

which seems to be the only place this could be an issue. Does anyone have any suggestion on finding the cause of this error.

A couple of other notes: each virtualhost is in a different file. mydomain.tld and my-domain.tld on a different ip address to anotherdomain.tld and another-domain.tld.

Comment: I have a couple ideas - but could you post the relevant vhosts configs? Obviously, feel free to edit the domain names out :)

Comment: Please paste the relevant bits of configuration -- it's much easier to see.

Comment: What happens if you put the name in quotes?

Comment: Are permissions set the same on your 4 config files?

Comment: Is it getting caught by your rewrite rules?

Answer (score 1):

How can you tell that the web server is serving anotherdomain.tld instead of another-domain.tld? Do you see that URL in the browser's address bar has anotherdomain.tld in it?

If you created these configuration with copy-paste technique, then you could have left the **DocumentRoot the same** for both domains.

Another guess is if anotherdomain.tld and another-domain.tld are configured on the same IP address for apache, but another-domain.tlp **DNS** "A" record is set up to a different IP, Apache HTTPD just pulls out the default VirtualHost for the IP specified in its configuration, which may be anotherdomain.tld.

Example: If you have in DNS:

```
 anotherdomain.tld ->  1.2.3.12
 another-domain.tld -> 1.2.3.12
```

Then in httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.12:80>
 ServerName anotherdomain.tld
  ...
</VirtualHost

<VirtualHost 1.2.3.18:80>
 ServerName another-domain.tld
  ...
</VirtualHost
```

When you type `http://another-domain.tld/`  in the browser's address bar, it makes a request to `1.2.3.12`, which pulls out the default virtual host for `1.2.3.12`, which is `anotherdomain.tld`.

These are just two wild guesses though...